# How can we remove first migration in Entity Framework Core Code first approach

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

As we know when we want to remove latest migration, We update the database to latest but one migration so we can remove the latest migration but if want to remove first migration don't have latest but one migration to update database into it, So not able to remove first migration, Can someone help with this.

Answer (score 1):

To reset the database to a clean state, prior to the first migration use

```
update-database 0
```

This will rollback the first migration.  Assuming you started with a new database, the only thing in the database at this point would be the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table.

At that point, you can use `Remove-Migration` to remove the very first migration.

You can also use `Update-Database 0` to create the initial database without any migrations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a table **EfMigrationsHistory** in your database . If you delete anyone of them and when you migrate , eframework will check that table .And it will see that the first migration does not exist and will update your database (alignment does not matter , I mean it could be 3rd or 8th migration).

And there is one class named BaseContextModelSnapshot , occasionally you need to edit if necessary .